# Achieve tablayout in composable

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I tried to achieve the same design of xml layout based style for tablayout in Jetpack Compose. But I am unable to reach the exact design.

Ignore the "SomeText" part in design. There can be any string from the list we are using.

The problem I am facing to achieve it is, the border of the tab not coming out of the TabRow border.
As the TabRow contains the tab, the black border of the selected tab is coming inside the TabRow only.
Any suggestions would help me.

[image]

Comment: You need to pass the border to custom item in TabRow otherwise its not possible to put border directly to the TabRow. If you share your code I can help more